# How to extract day of week given a date in HBase and Impala without integration with hive ？

Tags: hbase, impala

For example, 2019-08-09 is Friday. But in [Impala documentation](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html#datetime_functions),I could not find any function how to extract it.

Answer (score 1):

Impala also supports [dayofweek](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html#datetime_functions__dayofweek) function

```
select dayofweek("2019-08-11");

+-------------------------+
| dayofweek('2019-08-11') |
+-------------------------+
| 1                       |
+-------------------------+
```

For **`HBase`** you can create **hive table** on top of existing **hbase table** by using [Hive-Hbase integration](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-Usage) and then use **hive dayofweek/impala dayofweek(after performing `invalidate metadata`)** function to generate day of week for the column value.

Comment: unfortunately, I can't use hive table for some reasons. I just want to know if there is any syntax about Impala to do that.

Comment: @Jack, I don't think there is a way to execute these commands from impala :(